# PHP BB users post visible based on groups

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I am using the phpbb forum. I have created two Groups named :British Airways and Oman Airways. The post created by both airways will be treated differently. ie, The posts made by british airways will not see the post by oman Airways.

I hope you got my points. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution for you is to create two separate subforums and grant each forum only the permissions for the appropriate group.

For example, create a subforum called "British Airways Discussion". In the ACP, select the `Forums` tab, then `Forum permissions`. Under `Groups` add/remove the appropriate groups. In this case you'd add `British Airways`.

Repeat this for a subforum called "Oman Airways Discussion". In the ACP, add the `Oman Airways` group.

Now, each group will have their own area to discuss topics while not having permissions to see the other subforum.

Comment: Here we have 10 forums. So it wouldn't be practical to add these 10 forums to each group. Do you think its a proper way?And we have more than 20 Groups.